# Rails not able to render page as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a URL like this : `localhost/events/show?eId=12345.json`

When I perform : `model.find(params[:eId])`

It considers `.json` part of `eId` and says no id found for `12345.json`. To resolve this issue, I excluded `.json` from `eId` and it then shows the html page. But I need to be able to also see the `.json` page.

So it doesn't recognize that I need to view page as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `localhost/events/show.json?eId=12345`.

Comment: OMG I cannot believe I spent so much time for such a trivial thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or simply put `resources :events` in your routes then access it as `/events/12345.json` .